# Application Distribution

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I have a SDL app that compiles fine, and the images show up, but only if they are in the correct folder with the binary next to them, if the images are moved they wont show up next time the application is run. How can I make a complete binary that will allow me to compile the images as well as the code, so that I can distribute one single binary, and not a zip file with all of my assets. I have looked into writing a .deb file which is what I think I need, but the process looked complicated. I am running Ubuntu 10.10 I only need to distribute to Ubuntu

Comment: Would you prefer to embed the images (inflating the executable size and potentially making it un-runnable) or would you prefer to package the .deb for automated installation and maintenance?

Comment: I may be a bit wrong, but I think the usual "Linux way" of distributing media content with an application is not to embed it in the binary (I wasn't aware it was even possible), but to install it in /usr/share/your-application.

Comment: Automated installation would be preffered, unless it is going to add that much more complication to the deb creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making a .deb file. If you really seriously want to distribute anything for Ubuntu, you will have to get comfortable with dpkg sooner or later.

Now there is a Right Way to create packages, described in the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/).

And then there's [the dirty hippie way](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/#AEN88). For that you just need (a) a directory with a particular structure, containing all the files you want to distribute; (b) a control file with a particular format; and (c) [`dpkg-deb -b mydir`](http://man.he.net/man1/dpkg-deb) which produces `mydir.deb`. None of this is all that hard. You could be up and running in a few minutes.

Comment: I created a deb using the "dirty hippie way". The deb installs fine, but it still only works if the images are in the folder with the deb, if the folder is moved the program won't run. How can I make it so that the program doesn't rely on where the images are located on the users computer.

Comment: @FrozenWasteland Hmmm. How are you loading the images? `IMG_Load`? Are you using relative filenames or absolute?

Comment: I am loading the images using IMG_Load, and relative filenames.

Comment: Relative filenames will always fail if the current working directory isn't what the program expects. You can either `chdir(dirname(argv[0]))` in main(), or build absolute filenames based on `dirname(argv[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bin2c](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Embedding_PNG_Images#bin2c) to create embeddable static arrays.